# I did not understand how this program works

Tags: c

In the following program

```
#include<stdio.h>   
int main()    
{    
    char i=0;    
    for(i<=5 && i>=-1;++i;i>0)   
        printf("%d\t",i);
    return 0;    
}
```

'i' got printed from 1 to 127 then from -128 to -1.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 14):

That has got to be the most malformed for loop I have ever seen in my life.  For loops are formatted as follows

```
for ( initalization; condition; update )
```

at the beginning of a `for` loop, `initialization` occurs.  This is usually something like `i = 0`.  At the top of each loop, `condition` (normally something like `i < 5`)is evaluated in order to see if the loop should continue, and should the loop continue, `update` is executed (again, normally something like `++i`), and the loop executes once more.

Whats happening here, is the loop is using `++i` as the condition, so it will only terminate when `++i` evaluates to a `0` value, so you start at `1` and increment until the `char i` overflows from `128` to `-127`, and then continues incrementing until it reaches `-1`, at which point `++i` evaluates to `0` and the loop terminates

**EDIT**

So according to your code, `i<=5 && i>=-1` is performed at the very beginning of the first iteration of the loop (this accomplishes absolutely nothing), then `++i` is evaluated for boolean state (which being `0` to start, and using a pre-increment, the evaluation is `1` and therefore, not `0` so the boolean passes), and then the `update` section of `i>0` executes, which again, does nothing.

**EDIT2**

If your question was really about why it goes `1,2....128,-127,-126....-1` then Joachim provided a very good explanation of that behavior

Comment: Hah, didn't even notice that. Yeah, it's a pretty bad loop.

Comment: @WillihamTotland is this some condition? `i<=5 && i>=-1`

Comment: @Mr.Alien: The loop just straight up makes no sense.

Comment: @Mr.Alien It would indeed work, so long as the code contained in each segment of the different portions of the `for` loop is valid code.  The actual execution pattern of that loop is up to the actual implementation

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Had it worked there would not be a question here. ;) But yeah, it works, but not, it seems, as intended.

Comment: @DanF I've never tried something like this `i<=5 && i>=-1`, not even sure if it acts as a condition or what?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Based on its position in the `for` statement, it acts as the `initializer`.  I edited my answer a bit to provide an execution explanation of his actual code

Comment: Ya so probably an intialization condition like loop `if i<=5 && i>=-1`

Answer (score 3):

Good news: In your implementation, `char` is signed!

Also, what happens is that the value of `i` overflows from 127 to -128, because 127 is the biggest positive value that fits in a signed `char`.

**Edit:** Actually, I'm not sure about the signedness of `char` in your implementation, but the loop is utterly broken:

It should probably be

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
```

but that's just a guess. It's hard to interpret.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is a signed 8-bit integer in your compiler. It can represent values from -128 to +127. The loop end condition is `++i`, and in C all non-zero values are considered to be true, so it will loop until `++i` is zero which will happen when `i` is `-1`.

The reason that if goes from 127 to -128 is because how signed integers work in computer. The binary bits for 127 is `01111111`, and the bit pattern for -128 is `1000000`. Adding one to `01111111` will result in `10000000`.

All in all, your `for` loop makes no real sense. It's syntactically correct, but doesn't make any sense. For an explanation of how for-loops works see the answer by Dan F.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to read about [Two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Answer (score 1):

The program interprets "i" at print time as an 8-bit signed integer, meaning one bit for sign, seven bits for data. That gives you a range of -128 to 127 for valid values.

The "for" loop *preincrements* i before the printf, hence giving it a first-pass value of 1, and the increment continues until i+1=128 - which flips the sign bit in a signed integer, then runs the loop until ++i causes i to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, that for loop is horrible. You know it's supposed to be `for(intialisation; end condition; increment)`, right?

Anyway. i is initialised to 0; the first go round the for loop is testing the end condition (++i) which has a pre-increment. So i gets incremented to 1, the loop is run to print 1.

Now repeat. Each loop prints a one higher value for i because the end-condition test is pre-incrementing i.

Eventually i reaches 127; it then increments to 128, but you are printing it as "%d" which is expecting a signed integer, so using two's complement this is interpreted as -128.

The increment then continues all the way to 255 (printed as -1). The next pre-increment results in overflow so i becomes 0 again, at which point the "end condition test" evaluates to false and the loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

This programs has quite strange used for loop.
you initialize your loop variables by checking them "i<=5 && i>=-1" - no assignment is done.
during loop you evaluate the condition "++i" which is true until i = -1; and in the incrementation step you just check if the number is greater than zero.

You in fact do:

```
for(i = 1; i != 0; i++)
{
    printf("%d\t",i);
}
```

with overflow above 127 you get numbers from 1 to 127 and from -128 to -1.